# Can't get touchscreen to work on my tablet

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen, tablet

I have a chinese tablet with Innolux 8x12 on it. I managed to install Lubuntu 20.10 on it but touchscreen isn't working at all. I tried [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) and it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you know if this tablet will run that OS? You may need a driver for the touch screen from the manufacture.

Comment: You've provided no release details, are you talking about a *legacy* edition of Lubuntu? (using LXDE) or *modern* release (using LXQt), you've also not provided details as to what kernel stack you're using (if using a LTS release; ie. what ISO you installed; a GA or HWE kernel? selected by the ISO & release you installed with; as the kernel I suspect is very key and you've provided no details on what you're actually trying to use)

Comment: It's running Lubuntu flawlessly. Touch screen is the only problem I'm having right now. For the driver, I don't know what to do about it. I looked it up on the internet but I couldn't find anything. Should I contact them for support?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm new to this site and this community.I didn't know what to write. I'm using Lubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Kernel stack? How can I find that?

Comment: I think I found something. I typed "$ cat /proc/version_signature" in terminal. And got this: Ubuntu 5.8.0-48.54-generic 5.8.18. Is that enough or should I get more info for you?

Comment: Lubuntu 20.10 is not a LTS or *long-term-support* release, so only has a single kernel option (5.8).  LTS releases have two stack choices (eg. 20.04 could use the 5.4 GA kernel, or HWE kernel which currently is 5.8 from 20.10).  `uname -r` would have given you the *kernel* detail (same as you obtained in another way).  Your question ideally would have mentioned 20.10 as that detail alone answered all I asked.

Comment: So should I downgrade to 20.04 for HWE support? You think that is the key?

Comment: No it wouldn't provide anything but what you're already using... My comment was an attempt to provide detail on the stack choices I mention in my first comment (which apply to LTS releases, no need for non-LTS which is what you are using). I have no experience with your hardware sorry, but to try a later stack, you could try the 5.11 kernel used by *hirsute* (which is released as *beta* tomorrow, full release later this month). I'd try it as *live* to see if the 5.11 kernel provide support; if it doesn't then you'll need a module added, and I don't know what module that is

Comment: Ok, thanks guiverc.